# How can I get all the features in rally and group them by milestones in a custom grid?

Tags: html, css, grid, rally

I am looking to pull out features in Rally and group them by milestones and have some date filters,
also possibly getting child features and feature dependancies. I also want to get columns in the child features like ID, name, parent e.t.c

#Complete Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Grouped Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomGrid', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID','Name','ScheduleState',
         
                        ],
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        features: [{
                            ftype: 'groupingsummary',
                            groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})'
                        }],
                        storeConfig: {
                            model: 'feature',
                            groupField: 'Milestones',
                            groupDir: 'ASC',
          
                            fetch: ['Milestones'],
                            getGroupString: function(record) {
                                var Milestone = record.get('Milestones');
                                return (Milestone&&Milestone._refObjectName) || 'No Project';
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomGrid', {
              name: 'Custom Grid'
        });
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>`
```